# Why does Wordpress have such an awkward media migration experience?

Tags: wordpress, migration, database-migration

I've had to migrate many Wordpress web sites from different domains on the same server to different domains on different servers. In few cases, a simple export was sufficient. In many cases, an import failed to load the media correctly and I was forced to use a common work around.

Workaround (for those wondering):
I download from the original site and upload to the new site the uploads folder where my media is stored via FTP. Once this transfer is complete, I use the plugin Add From Server to select each individual image, one directory at a time.

This is the best workaround I've found, but it's hardly efficient. It's incredibly time consuming and stressful on your bandwidth.

If you have any better suggestions, I'm all ears. But primarily, I want to know the "Why" to this question. What causes Wordpress to have such a hard time managing media migration while migrating posts, pages, and users are much less of a headache?

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent tool that certainly eases Wordpress migration [WordPress (and others) Search and Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). With that tool it's easy to search through the entire database for all occurrences of old domain, and replace that with the name of new domain. After replacement all the pictures and widgets should work properly.

The way I'm moving WordPress:

1. export and import the database with phpMyAdmin
2. transfer the files with FTP program like FileZilla
3. edit the wp-config.php settings for a new domain
4. search and replace on the database with InterconnectIT Search and
   Replace Tool